# Chromecast does not play media from internal webserver

Tags: android, webserver, streaming, chromecast

I have a little app written, where you can choose different medias like video, mp3 and pictures.

For testing I have added some sample media like
Video - http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4, an mp3 file, and a picture.

These samples are working fine in chromecast.

Furthermore for better understanding I have not written a new receiver for chromecast. I am using the standard receiver from google.

Now I have a webserver running on my android phone. I have "installed" the correct mimeTypes "video/mp4 mp4" and when I enter the URL from my android phone in my webbrowser chrome on my laptop with the requested file (**192.168.0.12:5555/myvideo.mp4**) - it is working. 
So Chrome plays the file correctly.

The file myvideo.mp4 is the same video from the sample link:http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4. It is not another video.

But when I take this link (192.168.0.12:5555/myvideo.mp4) and send it to chromecast, chromecast tries to load the file and than goes back to the default screen, the same screen chromecast shows after successfully establishing a connection from my app. (Standard site from google)

I am working in Eclipse. It is not a programming problem. No errors.

I hope anybody can explain me, why chromecast doesn`t play my video, mp3 or jpg from my webserver, but plays the same files from the web?

Thanks
Paul

//EDIT
In the chromecast debugger I get the information:
**[151.045s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error**

I don`t know what i should do with this information. Also google haven`t heard this problem yet.

Thanks for any help

**//Solution**

I have put metadata to the mediafile and some metadata was false written. Eclipse didn`t show me an error, but chromecast had a problem with that.
So everybody who has the same problem, check your metadata of your file.

Hope I can help anybody with that

Comment: Have you looked at the console logs on your Cast device? Whitelist your device/app and then open a chrome debugger to your cast device on port 9222. That should tell you more about what is failing.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Thanks for the right direction :-)